# Integral inequality involving $e^{i\theta}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

I believe the below inequality is true;
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|a+e^{i\theta}\alpha b|^pd\theta\leq (1+\alpha)^p \int_0^{2\pi}|a+e^{i\theta} b|^pd\theta,$$
for any nonnegative reals $a, b, \alpha$ and $p>0.$

When $a=0$ or $b=0$ or $\alpha=1,$ the inequality is true.  May I know how to  verify if my claim is true or not. When $\alpha=1,$ the bound $(1+\alpha)^p$ appears relatively large, and therefore, is there any scope for sharpening this bound in my claim if the inequality is true in its current form?

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality we may assume $a=1.$ We want to show that for $\alpha=e^{y}$, $b=e^{x}$ and $q>1$ the following inequality holds
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|1+e^{i t}\alpha b|^{2q}dt\leq (1+\alpha )^{2q}\int_0^{2\pi}|1+e^{i t} b|^{2q}dt$$
Denoting $f_q(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\cosh x+\cos t)^qdt$ one sees  that the desired inequality is equivalent to
$$f_q(x+y)\leq (2(1+\cosh y))^q f_q(x)\ \ (*)$$
Let us show that $$f_q'(x)<qf_q(x)\ \ (**)$$ To see this we write
$$ f_q'(x)=q\sinh x f_{q-1}(x)\leq q\cosh x f_{q-1}(x)$$ and  we will use the following inequality for $R>r>0$  which is easily checked:
$$R(R+r)^{q-1}+R(R-r)^{q-1}\leq (R+r)^q+(R-r)^q\ \ (C)$$
The trick is to write $$f_q(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cosh x+\cos t)^qdt+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cosh x-\cos t)^qdt$$
and apply $(C)$ to $R=\cosh x$ and
$r=\cos t,$ obtaining $\cosh x f_{q-1}(x)\leq f_q(x)$ and a proof of (**), which can be rewritten as $\frac{d}{dx}\log f_q(x)\leq q.$ This implies
$$|\log f(x+y)-\log f(x)|\leq q|y|.$$ The only thing left to prove (*) is $|y|\leq \log 2(1+\cosh y)$ or $e^{|y|}\leq 2+e^{y}+e^{-y}$ which is obvious .

Comment: what about $0<q\leq 1$?

Comment: The above method does not work when $q<1.$. Inegality is still true when $q$ is very small, and this question is quite frustrating.